# Converting JSON file with multiple entries to XML

Tags: python, arrays, json, xml

My input json file looks something like this

```
{"id":1,"author":"abc","title":"xyz"}
{"id":2,"author":"def","title":"mno"}
```

I want a python script to create a xml file that looks like this

```
<sequence>
<id>1</id>
<author>abc</author>
<title>xyz</title>
</sequence>
<sequence>
<id>2</id>
<author>def</author>
<title>mno</title>
</sequence>
```

Right now this is the code I'm using

```
import json as j
with open("test.json") as json_format_file: 
  d = j.load(json_format_file)
import xml.etree.cElementTree as e
r = e.Element("sequence")
e.SubElement(r,"id").text = d["id"]
e.SubElement(r,"submitter").text = d["submitter"]
e.SubElement(r,"authors").text = str(d["authors"])
e.SubElement(r,"title").text = str(d["title"])

a = e.ElementTree(r)
a.write("json_to_xml.xml")
```

Problem is that it only works for 1 entry, and if i have more than 1 entry in the JSON file, it throws an error. How can I make this run for multiple entries and write it all into the xml file?

EDIT:
Have changed my JSON file to look like this

```
[{"id":1,"author":"abc","title":"xyz"},
{"id":2,"author":"def","title":"mno"}]
```

Comment: Your input file is invalid JSON. A valid json file would look like `[{"id":1,"author":"abc","title":"xyz"}, {"id":2,"author":"def","title":"mno"}]`

Comment: Ah okay, will it work if I change my JSON file to look like that?

Comment: At least then you could do `for inner_dict in d: ... ` and use `inner_dict["id"]` etc.

Comment: Ah okay, I shall check it out. ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json2xml is one of the powerful python library. Try this one.

**json.json**

```
[{"id":1,"author":"abc","title":"xyz"}, {"id":2,"author":"def","title":"mno"}]
```

**Python**

```
from json2xml import json2xml
import lxml.etree as ET
import json

with open('json.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


json2xml = json2xml.Json2xml(data, wrapper="sequence", pretty=True, attr_type=False).to_xml()
with open('json2xml.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json2xml)
    
    
## modifie xml data
tree = ET.parse('json2xml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for item in root.findall('item'):
    for child in item:
        root.append(child)
    root.remove(item)


new_xml = ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")
with open('file.xml', 'wb' ) as final:
    final.write(new_xml)
```

Comment: @chinnasddf I hope you got, what you want.

Comment: Im having a bit of trouble formatting it in these comments, but I think I'l be able to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the json data, make it into an array?

```
{
    "updated": "2020-07-09",
    "list": [
         {"id":1,"author":"abc","title":"xyz"},
         {"id":2,"author":"def","title":"mno"}
    ]
}

import json as j
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)
for obj in data['list']:

r = e.Element("sequence")

e.SubElement(r,"id").text = obj["list"]["id"]
e.SubElement(r,"submitter").text = obj["list"]["submitter"]
e.SubElement(r,"authors").text = str(obj["list"]["authors"])
e.SubElement(r,"title").text = str(obj["list"]["title"])   

a = e.ElementTree(r)

a.write("json_to_xml.xml")
```

Comment: If we're already doing 'for obj in data['list'], do we need to access values again using obj['list']['id'] or will obj['id'] work? Because I tried this right now and I got a KeyError:'list' in the line with obj['list']

Comment: oh, I modified the json format,  see the list array .